# Gridview not retaining old values in c# and ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an ASP.Net gridview which is binding properly.On edit i am editing certain fields.then after i need to edit other rows as well.But when i am trying to edit other rows the previously edited rows get reset n retain their older values.

The requirement is as such that i have to edit many rows and the on a button click i need to push all the edit values to the database

Comment: Did you place your code to update the database for many rows in the Row_Updating event? [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29745/A-GridView-with-Multiple-Selection) - This will help you make it multiselect. Then just get all the selected rows and get values from the GridView and write to the DB. If you having an issue with that I could help you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to maintain your GridView's datasource between postbacks.

You can do this by storing your DataTable in Cache, Session, or any persistent storage.

Upon edit of a row, save the changes to this DataTable, then rebind the Gridview (from this DataTable).

When the user clicks "save all", you can save the changed rows of the DataTable to the database.

If you need to keep track of which rows have changed, you can maintain a list of PrimaryKeys that have changed in cache or Session.

Comment: that is what my initial plan was...could you please provide a piece of code for doing this...any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? There would be a lot of code involved

Comment: lets say my gridview has n number of rows...i need code for storing these rows in a datatable then on rowediting i need to update this  datatable and bind it to the gridview

Comment: brian..should i stop waiting??

Comment: I can't really write all of that code for you due to time constraints. The best I can do is provide you the outline for the steps to follow. You will read values from your database into your datatable. You will maintain your datatable between postbacks in session state or cache. Then, upon save-all click you will check which datatable rows have changed and save to the database. If you don't know how to handle any of these steps, each step would be its own question. It is a large task.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking !IsPostBack  inside Page_Load event before binding the grid? If you are not binding the grid in Page_Load event, please post the code to bind the grid.

Comment: Hello WhizKid...you can please go through the code that i had posted...Thanks anyway for answering...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is,you r binding grid on page load.. so when page is loading , it can bind the values which are in database. for that write bind method on Post back and also maintain your values on sessions or Hidden Fields,when you click on save button update database with that sessions or hidden fields..

Comment: No Manoj...My binding Method is no where in the page load... The BindGrid Is called in the SelectedIndexChanged Event of a Dropdown..and then the Above Function getGridInfo() is called inside the BindGrid...I am sure you'll Understand it...Thanks

Comment: are you Check Enable Auto Postback Property for dropdown

Comment: ofcourse, the autoPostback property of the dropdown must be true in order to execute anything you want on its index change..

Answer (score 0):

morning bryan...here is that code for getting the value from the gridview to the datatable

private void getGridInfo()

{

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr;
    dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Select", typeof(byte)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Client", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("PrincipleAmt", typeof(double)));



    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdRepayment.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox Select = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("ChkSelect");
        Label ClientName = (Label)row.FindControl("lblClientName");
        Label Principal = (Label)row.FindControl("lblPricipal");

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = Convert.ToByte(Select.Checked);
        dr[1] = ClientName.Text;
        dr[2] = Convert.ToDouble(Principal.Text);

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    Session["TempTable"] = dt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

now here is the code for updating that session variable which holds the datatable,this must be done in RowUpdating Event of the Gridview.

protected void grdRepayment_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)

{

```
        DataTable myDatatable;
        GridViewRow row = grdRepayment.Rows[e.RowIndex]; 
        grdRepayment.EditIndex = -1; 

        if (row != null)
        {
            myDatatable = (DataTable)Session["TempTable"];
            for (int i = 0; i < myDatatable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (e.RowIndex == i)
                {

                    myDatatable.Rows[i][1] = Convert.ToString(Client);
                    myDatatable.Rows[i][2] = Convert.ToString(Principal);

                    Session["TempTable"] = myDatatable;
                    grdRepayment.EditIndex = -1;
                    grdRepayment.DataSource = myDatatable;
                    grdRepayment.DataBind();

                }
            }
        }
      }
```

and make sure you bind the grid from this session variable only in RowEditing and RowCancellingEdit Events.
Once you are done with the Editing thing simply click the button which will push the edited content to the DATABASE...

Answer (score 0):

Please check you'r gridview binding method was call page load and inside of !isPostBack?

for

```
Void page_load()
{
if(!IsPostBack)

{
//Call GridView Binding method
}

}
```

Comment: My binding Method is no where in the page load... The BindGrid Is called in the SelectedIndexChanged Event of a Dropdown

Comment: Must call your binding method  page load event inside of !IsPostBack

for My Post way.Please check my answer.

Comment: no ramesh..my requirement is as such that the grid must not pop up when the page loads..rather it should load when i select something from the dropdown...Thanks Anyway

Answer (score 0):

protected void grdRepayment_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)

{

```
    grdRepayment.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    myDatatable = (DataTable)Session["TempTable"];
    grdRepayment.DataSource = myDatatable;
    grdRepayment.DataBind();

}
```

This is how we need to Bind the grid in RowEditing and RowCancelingEdit